# RxJava Network calls takes time to call Webservice

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, retrofit, okhttp

I have asked question recently on stackoverflow regarding my [slow network calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41629057/how-to-asynchronously-call-retrofit-request-of-the-current-ui-action) using Retrofit and RxJava

I have made some changes of scheduler.io in it and removed main thread from all the execution. But still the result is not that much satisfying. I have digged in the code of OkHttp and Retrofit. Below are my findings:

- Retrofit uses scheduler.io which will execute all the requests in the threadpool. Previously it was creating new threads. Does changing it to scheduler.io from newthread make any difference?
- Now OkHttp has limit of max requests per host of 5 in the code. So does that make any difference?
- All the calls are happening in Dispatcher using enqueue. Do we need to set some configuration to Retrofit and OkHttp for that?

Any suggestions to increase the performance of webservice call will be appreciated?

Comment: was it the requesting part or the rendering part of the call ?

Comment: Are you creating new `Retrofit` instance for each service call or creating a global instance and using it throughout the app?

Comment: For the requesting part of the call

Comment: I am using MVP structure. In that I am creating retrofit instance first time in Presenter. In that presenter, I am covering all the webservices related to the screen. Does creating new Retrofit instance make any difference? If yes,  Can you please explain how?

Comment: How much time does the OkHttp Interceptor takes to process generally?